# Samsung S7 Edge phone not loading android application images

Tags: android, image, samsung-mobile

I have tested my android application in different phones but I found some issue in Samsung S7 edge. It is not loading images instead there is an empty space as in below image. All functions work correctly.

[image]

This is the xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/himage" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="268dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="#e60000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/b_txt"
                    android:layout_width="260dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Sample text"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="268dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#027647"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/d_txt"
                    android:layout_width="260dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Sample text"
                    android:textColor="#ffdd53"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/c_btn"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_t_white_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:shadowColor="#014b2e"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="@string/ctxt"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

           <Button
            android:id="@+id/ca_btn"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_v_white_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:shadowColor="#014b2e"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="@string/ca_txt"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_btn"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
             android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_e_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:shadowColor="#014b2e"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="@string/bo_txt"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


            <Button
            android:id="@+id/te_btn"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
             android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_d_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:shadowColor="#014b2e"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="@string/te_txt"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/lo_btn"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lo_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:shadowColor="#014b2e"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="@string/lo_txt"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/re_btn"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
             android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_p_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:shadowColor="#014b2e"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="@string/re_txt"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

            android:src="@drawable/cpic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/site"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#027647"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="268dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#027647"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cusNo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:textColor="#ffdd53"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

What should be the image size for this phone? Any suggestion or help would be appreciated to solve this issue. 
If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: what is the image library you are using ?

Comment: @kareemadel What I did is, I create hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi sizes for the images and add them to the relevant folders. Do you have any other suggestion to do this?

Comment: It depends on the application you are creating, if you are using only static images then this should work, please provide the layout xml file.

Comment: @kareemadel I have added my xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because of your phone screen has high resolution，put your pictures in hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi.maybe it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, and this worked for me:

If you're using Android studio, click on your image and in the properties pane choose your images as **background** property instead of **srcCompat**.

If this works, then there is also a chance your images wont appear in the correct size so you will have to resize them manually.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Are you using eclipse?

Comment: Your welcome. I've been using Android studio, so I just assumed you used that too. I'm not sure about eclipse though.

Answer (score 0):

From the XML file there is a big background image that might be taking a lot of memory and therefore causing it not to show, therefore you could always increase the heap of your application by adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in the android manifest in the Application tag, however do not use this unless there is no way that you can reduce the size of the used images.